# Django Test Fail sometimes and sometime succecss, what is possible reason?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tests

I have written testcase and i found my testcase is ok. I run the test and it fires me ok message, i run frequently the same test, it fires me ok message..

But the problem, sometime it fires me fail message.. what is possible reason? I could share the code here but i found no reason to show the code. coz, the problem is not with code... the problem is awkwardness...

I think if the test return succecss message, it should return success message forever, why it returns fail message sometimes? even i dont change any code in the meantime, yet it return fails or success..

for example, i write test and i run it, i found it success.. if run it 2 minutes later, it retruns fail message, (sometime success) whats wrong with system?

I hope you got the issue?

What is possible solution for this issue? how can skip this situation?

Comment: We can't do much with a "sometime it fails".

Comment: it has no solution? are you sure?

Comment: There are for sure but we can't do without at least the code